# Class HTML not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an application with laravel 4. I have created a function like below:

```
/**
     * Create  link to named action with icon.
     * 
     * 
     * @param  string $icon
     * @param  string $action
     * @param  string $text
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return string
     */
    public static function fa_link_to_action($icon, $action, $title = null, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array()) {
        $url = action($action, $parameters);

        $title = (is_null($title)) ? $url : e($title);

        $attributes = HTML::attributes($attributes);

        $title .= '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-' . e($icon) . '"></span>';

        return '<a href="' . $url . '"' . $attributes . '>' . $title . '</a>';

    }
```

And i call this function at view like this:

```
{{ Helpers\Helper::fa_link_to_action('pencil','CarController@edit','Edit',$v->id,         array( 'class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round')) }}
```

The problem is that it shows :
class Helper\HTML not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably working inside of a namespace. There are two option for handling this:

1. Adding a slash before `HTML::` instances like so `\HTML::`.
2. Add `use HTML;` after the namespace declaration.

The latter is the cleanest and I think creates the most elegant solution. It prevent your code from looking ugly, is less prone to typo's and gives you a good overview of the classes you are using.